# AWS/EB - getting hit with internal dummy connection

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just deployed a simple django app to Elastic Beanstalk. The landing page(which has a login form) loads without issue.

When I submit the login form nothing happens,  I just see `Waiting for awsapp.sdfkjldsf.elasticbeanstalk.com` which eventually times out.

When I look at the error logs I see the following repeated over and over

`::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:22:50 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"`

Being new to Django/AWS/EB I'm not sure how to debug this.

I've attached the logs below:

```
    Retrieving logs...
    ============= i-e9245931 ==============
    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/eb-version-deployment.log
    -------------------------------------
    2016-03-28 14:11:31,444 [INFO] Found the latest version manifest file <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-226428845556,resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/versions/manifest_1459174126708> from bucket elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-226428845556 and prefix resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/versions/
    2016-03-28 14:11:31,496 [INFO] Downloaded the manifest file to /tmp/version_file_manifest
    2016-03-28 14:11:31,592 [INFO] Downloaded version label app-160328_070839 from s3 key <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-226428845556,resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/_versions/MY_APP/app-160328_070839>
    2016-03-28 14:17:05,827 [INFO] Version manifest file name already known. The latest version manifest file key is resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/versions/manifest_1459174584476
    2016-03-28 14:17:05,881 [INFO] Downloaded the manifest file to /tmp/version_file_manifest
    2016-03-28 14:17:05,951 [INFO] Downloaded version label app-160328_071617 from s3 key <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-226428845556,resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/_versions/MY_APP/app-160328_071617>
    2016-03-28 14:24:03,188 [INFO] Version manifest file name already known. The latest version manifest file key is resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/versions/manifest_1459175039089
    2016-03-28 14:24:03,243 [INFO] Downloaded the manifest file to /tmp/version_file_manifest
    2016-03-28 14:24:03,319 [INFO] Downloaded version label app-160328_072353 from s3 key <Key: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-226428845556,resources/environments/e-te3pnfnm7y/_runtime/_versions/MY_APP/app-160328_072353>



    -------------------------------------
    /opt/python/log/supervisord.log
    -------------------------------------
    2016-03-28 14:11:37,813 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
    2016-03-28 14:11:37,829 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
    2016-03-28 14:11:37,829 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
    2016-03-28 14:11:37,829 INFO supervisord started with pid 2625
    2016-03-28 14:11:38,831 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 2708
    2016-03-28 14:11:40,565 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2016-03-28 14:17:11,556 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)
    2016-03-28 14:17:12,560 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3238
    2016-03-28 14:17:13,594 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
    2016-03-28 14:24:11,683 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)
    2016-03-28 14:24:12,688 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3630
    2016-03-28 14:24:13,732 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/httpd/error_log
    -------------------------------------
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:08.666295 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3238] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.732219 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 3630] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.741309 2016] [so:warn] [pid 3630] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.743477 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3630] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.744008 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3630] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.744042 2016] [:warn] [pid 3630] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9.
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.744045 2016] [:warn] [pid 3630] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.10.
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.745762 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3630] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Mon Mar 28 14:24:12.745775 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3630] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/httpd/access_log
    -------------------------------------
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 122541 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 23358 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/css/MY_APP.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2385 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/js/jquery-2.1.4.js HTTP/1.1" 200 247598 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 36817 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.40.173 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:01 +0000] "GET /static/sub_app/js/MY_APP.js HTTP/1.1" 200 999 "http://MY_APP.menmjmyimv.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/login?next=/verify" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:11 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:12 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:13 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:15 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:16 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:17 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:18 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:19 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:20 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:29:27 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:30:15 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:30:20 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:31:04 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:35:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:35:09 +0000] "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1694 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:35:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:35:15 +0000] "GET /login?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1694 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:09 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:16 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:17 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:18 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:19 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:21 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:25 +0000] "GET /verify HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    172.31.23.38 (75.164.143.24) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:36:25 +0000] "GET /login?next=/verify HTTP/1.1" 200 1694 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:37:25 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:37:30 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:37:34 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"
    ::1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2016:14:38:03 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 (internal dummy connection)"



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/eb-activity.log
    -------------------------------------
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/selector-icons.svg'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/calendar-icons.svg'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/LICENSE'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/gis/move_vertex_on.svg'
      Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/img/gis/move_vertex_off.svg'

      63 static files copied to '/opt/python/bundle/3/sub_app/static'.

    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
      CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.441Z] INFO  [3918]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Completed activity. Result:
      CMD-TailLogs - stage  - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage ] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs] : Starting activity...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  - [CMD-TailLogs - stage /TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



    -------------------------------------
    /var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
    -------------------------------------

    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.965Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.965Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-e9245931)..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-e9245931)..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: 
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : Command processor should execute command.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Storing current stage..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs - stage 
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] INFO  [3918]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.967Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-03-28T14:35:56.968Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Refreshing metadata..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.216Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.216Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.217Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.217Z] INFO  [3918]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] INFO  [3918]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] INFO  [3918]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.218Z] INFO  [3918]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] INFO  [3918]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] DEBUG [3918]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.219Z] INFO  [3918]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.440Z] INFO  [3918]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
    [2016-03-28T14:35:57.441Z] INFO  [3918]  : Command processor returning results: 
    {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-e9245931] Successfully finished tailing 6 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1459175757441}]}]}
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.133Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.133Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-e9245931)..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-e9245931)..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: 
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : Command processor should execute command.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Storing current stage..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs - stage 
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] INFO  [3972]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.135Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Refreshing metadata..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.380Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.380Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.380Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.381Z] INFO  [3972]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish"].
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Setting environment variables..
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] DEBUG [3972]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
    [2016-03-28T14:38:26.382Z] INFO  [3972]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It ended up that my app didn't have access to the database.

Comment: How did you work this out? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: check your `DATABASES` in `settings.py` - it turned out that mine were not set up correctly. I was confusing RDS database name with the table name(I was using similar names in both)